# Lessc Scale or alternatives

Tags: javascript, less, handlebars.js, mustache

I am looking for the correct ways to generate css files from less dynamically without breaking the server.

The users of the widget choose their color scheme and they add the widget to their site. The widget load then downloads the preferences (color schemes etc.) and I am looking for way how to generate css from the prefs.

Generating css for each user increases the load times and I would like to get everything done at the client side.

Including less.js would be an additional load on the page times and I would like to avoid it. I am open to using mustache or handlebars for dynamically generating the css but there are certain elements like darken, lighten etc. which I am not sure how to generate using javascript.

What is the right way of generating css in this way? Is generating css for each user the right way.

Comment: Only the first hit to a properly-cached static javascript resource should "take load time".

Answer (score 0):

When you're generating the user's page, use a generated file name (e.g. including a hash of user's settings) in the `link` element. Then when serving that CSS, compile it serverside, and put caching headers onto it. This way, as long as the settings remain the same, the file name remains the same, and the browser will use the cached version. When settings change, file name changes, and it's not in cache any more, triggering a recompilation on the server.